# How can I specify which network interface OkHttp will use when establishing new connections

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using `OkHttp` within an application I run on a server, and the server has multiple network interfaces configured at the OS level.

How I can control which network interface OkHttp will to use to send new requests?

By default, I see it simply selects one of the interfaces available, where as I would like to provide users of my application built on top of OkHttp the ability to configure the interface which should be used.

Comment: What is your criteria for selecting a network interface over another for a given request?

Comment: Not really clear why it's considered too broad, it's a very specific question with a discrete answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#socketFactory-javax.net.SocketFactory-

```
public OkHttpClient.Builder socketFactory(SocketFactory socketFactory)
```

> Sets the socket factory used to create connections. OkHttp only uses
> the parameterless createSocket() method to create unconnected sockets.
> Overriding this method, e. g., allows the socket to be bound to a
> specific local address. If unset, the system-wide default socket
> factory will be used.

For example https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/e307022667e2beb474309af5b350cd241f2a9045/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/network/InterfaceSocketFactory.kt

```
class InterfaceSocketFactory(private val localAddress: InetAddress) : SocketFactory() {
  private val systemFactory = getDefault()

  override fun createSocket(): Socket {
    val s = systemFactory.createSocket()
    s.bind(InetSocketAddress(localAddress, 0))
    return s
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

If just for testing, you can setup Http proxy with the tool named Charles. Maps the url to the remote interface you want.